# NSUrlRequest cache policy issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

So I am a little bummed with an issue but I am just trying to see if this is root cause of my problem.

I am setting an `set_active` flag in my app, and it basically tells the server that the user is active, and the server returns `200 OK`. This call is made every time the app is in foreground, and it is definitely getting called.

Issue is that for users who have installed the app for a very long time, this api call is never made.

At first I am digging through my code for logical flaws, but I am unable to identify this as there does not seem to be any issues (at least on dev side I can see for sure this is called). On the server side, this call is never made - so it's proof that the client DID NOT make this call.

Would there by any issue with URL caching may be?

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/profiles/set_active?session=%@", SERVER_END_POINT, self.sessionKey];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             CXProdLog(@"set active");
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             CXProdLog(@"set active failed");
         }];
```

Is there any way this can haunt me `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` if app keeps calling it? Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Where are you calling it and how ? The cache policy is not a problem. Either the request fails or it is never made.

Comment: The request is always made. The call does not reach the server - or we would know if it failed or not.

Comment: Interesting. Try making it reach localhost and try from Simulator.

Comment: Negative. This does not show up in testing. The users who are affected are the really old ones. They have the most recent build though.